# How to organise my maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I'm sure that this has been answered elsewhere, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding fully how to organise my project hierarchy.

So I've got a project that I'm working on, it holds lots of utilities that I use in various other projects.

lets call the main part of the project `MyProject.org.utils`

Underneath this I have a logical separation of parts for things such as 
 - Logging and 'custom exceptions'
 - Calendar / time functions
 - string functions.

I'm using eclipse and have created each of these as 'packages' underneath `MyProject.org.utils`.

I want to be able to do 2 things for this project.

I would like to be able to release a single jar for each sub part, so one jar with all the stuff for the logging and another for calendar functions.

This would mean If I don't need to import these into another project I don't need to (particularly for my logging stuff, which I use in all my other projects, but often I don't use the calendar stuff).

I'm sure that this can be done in my Maven `pom.xml` but I'm not sure how to set it up for this.

I've read about parent poms, but I'm not convinced I understand how to get this to work in my situation, as I have only a single `pom.xml` in my workspace.

I would like to keep all of these parts within the same project in my eclipse workspace.

This is the current tree setup for this project, which I think helps better helps explain what I want to do (trimmed for brevity):

```
├── log4j2.xml
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── myproject
│   │   │       └── org
│   │   │           └── utils
│   │   │               ├── calendar
│   │   │               ├── logging
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── myproject
│   │       │       └── org
│   │       │           └── utils
│   │       │               ├── calendar
│   │       │               ├── logging
│   │       └── resources
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│
│...
```

So essentially I want a jar for :
`myproject.org.utils.calendar`
`myproject.org.utils.logging`

but how to modify my `pom.XML` to get this.

I think I need to have a parent `pom.xml`, but where do I then put the child `pom.xml` files for the 2 jars that I want to create?

Or am I going about this in the wrong way?
Short examples and links to tutorials, etc. would be perfect,
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

David

Comment: The *main* folder should be under the *src* folder. And you also need the *src/main/resources* folder, where you should put files like your *log4j2.xml*. The *test* folder should be at the same level to the *main* folder. On how to obtain your jar file, please refer to the [maven jar plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/). And last, the *target* foulder is generated from maven when you build your project, and deleted on *mvn clean*.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Thanks for that info. Sorry for the error with main. it was a bad copy / paste from the terminal. I've read the maven jar plugin docs that you link to, but I must admit I'm not completely sure I understand how to write this into my pom.xml. I'm sure it somehow involves using the ``<included>`` configuration, but I feel I should be giving each one it's own artifact ID, is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should create maven project (aka pom.xml) for each calendar and logging stuff. The packaging of the poms should have the default value **jar**. Note, that each of the projects (calendar and logging) has a separated physical location and there is no a common src folder, like in your snippet. This does not affect the name of packages or jars and you can use the common prefix for them.

I recommend to create the parent maven project for them and include calendar and logging projects as modules into the parent pom. The parent pom packaging should be **pom**. There is no target for the parent pom - since jars are produces by the modules. Parent pom makes easier managing dependencies, versions, plugins etc.

All that may be easily defined with eclipse (File->New->Maven->Maven project etc.)

You can see working example on [git](https://github.com/alasch1/CodePreference). Probably it worth to read maven manual for getting background.

Just for others who may come along, this is the better process.
 - create the initial maven project (using eclipse new -> maven project, or the command line).
 - to create the child package you should select new -> Maven module

This will result in a file structure of the following

```
├── myproject.org.utils.calendar
│   ├── src
|   │   ├── main
|   │   └── test
│   └── target
├── src
│   ├── main
|   │   ├── main
|   |   │   └── java
|   |   |   │   └── myproject.org.utils.calendar_old
```

You will notice how in the above tree the newly created maven module (`myproject.org.utils.calendar`) site in the root of the main project, rather than how a typical eclipse new->java->package sits under `src\main\java`.

This new module (`myproject.org.utils.calendar`) contains its own pom.xml and the outer 'parent' project now has this as part of the a `<modules>` section in its pom.xml

Comment: So what I should have done was create 2 independent maven project. myproject.org.utils.calendar and myproject.org.utils.logging. Then after created a new project just called myproject.org.utils and then pulled the others into this project ? I think that my method had created a worse mess for myself. Is there going to be an way to straighten it out ? (eclipse or from the cli). Thanks

Comment: Nope. just like I wrote.But it is not such big deal - eclipse will help you.

Comment: I've edited your reply to better explain how the difference looks and how to generate this in eclipse. Hope you don't mind. When you accept the edit (or make changes as you see fit) I will accept your answer.